# Частичная инициализация вектора

Tags: c++, vector, конструктор

Для последовательной инициализации элементов в вектор их можно добавлять через `push_back` и `emplace_back`. А что если есть некоторая перестановка индексов, в соответствии с которой надо заполнить вектор? Получается, мне надо сначала изменить размер вектора, а потом заполнять его по индексам. Но при изменении размера он сразу же заполняется дефаултными значениями, т. е. для каждого элемента вызывается дефаултный конструктор.

**Есть ли способ заполнить вектор не подряд и при этом не вызывать дефаултный конструктор?** Т. е. интересует аналог следующей функции `fill_p`, который работает аналогично, но не выводит `no args`.

https://ideone.com/fAKFeW

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct smth
{
  smth() { cout << "no args" << endl; }
  smth(int x) { cout << "with x = " << x << endl; }
};

void fill_pb()
{
  cout << "=== fill_pb ===" << endl;

  vector <smth> v;
  for (int q=0; q<3; ++q) v.push_back(q);

  cout << endl;
}

void fill_eb()
{
  cout << "=== fill_eb ===" << endl;

  vector <smth> v;
  for (int q=0; q<3; ++q) v.emplace_back(q);

  cout << endl;
}

void fill_p(vector <int> p)
{
  cout << "=== fill_p ===" << endl;

  vector <smth> v(p.size());
  for (int q=0; q<p.size(); ++q) v[p[q]] = p[q];

  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  fill_pb();
  fill_eb();
  fill_p({3,1,0,2});

  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
=== fill_pb ===
with x = 0
with x = 1
with x = 2

=== fill_eb ===
with x = 0
with x = 1
with x = 2

=== fill_p ===
no args
no args
no args
no args
with x = 3
with x = 1
with x = 0
with x = 2
```

Comment: Возможности, инициализировать элементы вектора в произвольном порядке - нет. Вычислите обратную перестановку для заданной, тогда можно будет инициализировать элементы в правильном порядке.

Comment: Вы хотите заполнить, допустим, 5, 10, 15 элементы...   А что делать с теми,  что лежат между ними???  Особенно когда они вдруг понадобятся?  И как отследить,  при доступе на чтение,  был это элемент инициализирован или нет?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, предполагается заполнение всех элементов но не в порядке возрастания индексов. Скорее всего я ожидаю что-то по принципу "если оставил дыры, то UB при обращении к ним или в деструкторе".

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется,  у Вас получается неоправданное усложнение.  Может лучше бы подошло что-то типа ассоциативного массива или упорядоченного списка?

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда в вашем коде fill_p уже имеется UB - ```v[p[q]] = p[q];```, ведь объект ```v[p[q]]``` никто не создавал, но Вы ему что-то присваиваете.

Comment: @Croessmah, хм.. точно, присваивание же будет вызывать деструктор на мусорной памяти если сначала не инициализировать. Нужно какое-то конструирование на месте, как это с push_back и emplace_back работает...

Comment: Стандартный вектор такой интерфейс не поддерживает. Такой вектор бы вынуждал бы ещё хранить массив с информацией был ли вызван констуктов, или только выделена память. В качестве варианта можно использовать vector<unique_ptr<T>>. Теоретически, можно сэкономить на переходе по ссылке, написав структуру, которая содержит флаг и массив размера объекта. И конструктор с дестуктором при необходимости вызывать явно (у оператора new и delete есть перегрузки, которые это делают без выделения/очистки памяти). Но, кажется, переход по ссылке не то, что может сильно посадить производительность.